# How can i upload different files per thread in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I can currently upload a file to a web service using a POST and path of the files.
JMeter 2.13

When running the tests with 1 thread it uploads all the files in the directory to the web service. If I run it with 2 threads it uploads all the files twice.

I want to be able to send x amount random files per thread but don't want to send the same files again.

Any advice on how I can do this without using a CSV file?

Comment: you need to randomize values in filename?

Comment: @user7294900 I don't want to use a file to do it I want to be able to point at a folder and make JMeter pick 10 files per thread.

Comment: Create different folders containing random files and name them Folder1, Folder2.....add a counter to your script and use in your parameter name like this "Folder${Counter} so each time it will pick up the next folder containing different files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see at least 2 possible solutions:

1. Using [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) plugin. It has `KEEP=FALSE` option so the file will be removed from the list after uploading. You can install HTTP Simple Table Server using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

   [image: JMeter Plugins JMeter Plugins Manager]
2. Use the following approach:

   - in [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to copy folder with your test files into a temporary location, the relevant Groovy code will be something like:

     ```
     org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(new File('/path/to/source/folder'), new File('/path/to/destination/folder'))
     ```
   - after file upload request you can delete the file which has already been used in the [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) like:

     ```
     new File('/path/to/the/file').delete()
     ```